# Unable to instrument file: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError android/content/ComponentCallbacks

Tags: android, gradle, code-coverage, cobertura, android-instrumentation

I am trying to generate Cobertura coverage reports for the (multi module) Android project I'm working on.
The project was already there when I started implementing code coverage. The app that is the result of this project runs fine on all used devices.

We start Gradle tasks from the command line, so that we can also execute them on our Jenkins CI server.
The command I run is:

```
gradlew clean cobertura testDebug checkDebug assembleRelease
```

I've also tried different orders of commands. It did not help very much. 
The other cobertura commands described in Usage.md did not help either.

The Cobertura process runs well until the task :app:instrument starts to run.
After a short while multiple NoClassDefFoundError are thrown.
It results in a zero percent coverage for the classes involved, for instance my MainActivity class.
A lot of error messages pop up. Please see the stacktrace:

```
:app:compileDebugAidl                 
:app:compileDebugRenderscript                 
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig                 
:app:mergeDebugShaders                 
:app:compileDebugShaders                 
:app:generateDebugAssets                 
:app:mergeDebugAssets                 
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE      
:app:generateDebugResources                 
:app:mergeDebugResources                 
:app:processDebugManifest                 
:app:processDebugResources                 
:app:generateDebugSources                 
:app:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard                 
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac                 
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
:app:incrementalDebugUnitTestJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE      
:app:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE      
:app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies                 
:app:compileDebugUnitTestJavaWithJavac                 
:app:compileDebugUnitTestJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE                    
:app:processDebugUnitTestJavaRes                 
:app:compileDebugUnitTestSources                 
:app:mockableAndroidJar UP-TO-DATE      
:app:assembleDebugUnitTest                 
:app:instrument                                                              
Cobertura 2.1.1 - GNU GPL License (NO WARRANTY) - See COPYRIGHT file
Unable to instrument file C:\Code\Android\PhilipsPolaris\app\build\instrumented_classes\com\philips\polaris\activity\MainActivity.class
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/content/ComponentCallbacks
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.CoberturaClassWriter.getCommonSuperClass(CoberturaClassWriter.java:32)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter.a(Unknown Source)
        at org.objectweb.asm.Frame.a(Unknown Source)
        at org.objectweb.asm.Frame.a(Unknown Source)
        at org.objectweb.asm.MethodWriter.visitMaxs(Unknown Source)
        at org.objectweb.asm.MethodVisitor.visitMaxs(Unknown Source)
        at org.objectweb.asm.util.CheckMethodAdapter.visitMaxs(Unknown Source)
        at org.objectweb.asm.MethodVisitor.visitMaxs(Unknown Source)
        at org.objectweb.asm.commons.LocalVariablesSorter.visitMaxs(Unknown Source)
        at org.objectweb.asm.tree.MethodNode.accept(Unknown Source)
        at org.objectweb.asm.util.CheckMethodAdapter$1.visitEnd(Unknown Source)
        at org.objectweb.asm.MethodVisitor.visitEnd(Unknown Source)
        at org.objectweb.asm.util.CheckMethodAdapter.visitEnd(Unknown Source)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.b(Unknown Source)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
        at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.CoberturaInstrumenter.instrumentClass(CoberturaInstrumenter.java:214)
        at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.CoberturaInstrumenter.instrumentClass(CoberturaInstrumenter.java:129)
        at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.CoberturaInstrumenter.addInstrumentationToSingleClass(CoberturaInstrumenter.java:243)
        at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.CodeInstrumentationTask.addInstrumentationToSingleClass(CodeInstrumentationTask.java:299)
        at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.CodeInstrumentationTask.addInstrumentation(CodeInstrumentationTask.java:308)
        at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.CodeInstrumentationTask.addInstrumentation(CodeInstrumentationTask.java:317)
        at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.CodeInstrumentationTask.addInstrumentation(CodeInstrumentationTask.java:317)
        at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.CodeInstrumentationTask.addInstrumentation(CodeInstrumentationTask.java:317)
        at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.CodeInstrumentationTask.addInstrumentation(CodeInstrumentationTask.java:317)
        at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.CodeInstrumentationTask.addInstrumentation(CodeInstrumentationTask.java:317)
        at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.CodeInstrumentationTask.instrument(CodeInstrumentationTask.java:90)
        at net.sourceforge.cobertura.dsl.Cobertura.instrumentCode(Cobertura.java:74)
        at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.InstrumentMain.instrument(InstrumentMain.java:82)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:192)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:56)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
        at net.saliman.gradle.plugin.cobertura.CoberturaRunner.executeCobertura(CoberturaRunner.groovy:224)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:210)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:59)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:190)
        at net.saliman.gradle.plugin.cobertura.CoberturaRunner.instrument(CoberturaRunner.groovy:89)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:169)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:71)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:149)
        at net.saliman.gradle.plugin.cobertura.InstrumentTask.instrument(InstrumentTask.groovy:145)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:227)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:220)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:209)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:585)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:568)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:203)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:185)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:66)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:50)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:25)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:110)
        at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$4.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:154)
        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:52)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:151)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:99)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:62)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:82)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:94)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:78)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:48)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:170)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:33)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:130)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.content.ComponentCallbacks
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 178 more            
Unable to instrument file C:\Code\Android\PhilipsPolaris\app\build\instrumented_classes\com\philips\polaris\activity\SplashActivity$1.class
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.content.Intent
        at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.CoberturaClassWriter.getCommonSuperClass(CoberturaClassWriter.java:35)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter.a(Unknown Source)
        at org.objectweb.asm.Frame.a(Unknown Source)
        at org.objectweb.asm.Frame.a(Unknown Source)         
:app:copyCoberturaDatafile                 
:app:testDebugUnitTest                                       
[INFO] Cobertura: Loaded information on 179 classes.         
[INFO] Cobertura: Saved information on 179 classes.          
:app:cobertura                                               
:app:generateCoberturaReport                 
Cobertura 2.1.1 - GNU GPL License (NO WARRANTY) - See COPYRIGHT file
Report time: 649ms                           
:app:performCoverageCheck SKIPPED                     

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 3 mins 51.432 secs
```

I think the problem is similar to issue #100.

PROJECT.GRADLE

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
        classpath "net.saliman:gradle-cobertura-plugin:2.3.1"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

BUILD.GRADLE (app module)
android {
    dexOptions {
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'
    compileOptions.encoding = 'ISO-8859-1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.my.app"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 31
        versionName "0.21.1"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        renderscriptTargetApi 14
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
        generatedDensities = []
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            testCoverageEnabled true
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ["libs"]
        }
        test {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ["libs"]
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

cobertura {
    coverageFormats  = ['html']
    coverageIncludes = ['.*com.my.app.*']
    coverageExcludes = [
            ".*com.my.app.shadows.*",
            ".*\\.package-info.*",
            ".*\\.R.*",
            ".*BuildConfig.*",
            ".*Manifest.*"
    ]
    androidVariant = "debug"
//    auxiliaryClasspath = files(new File("$buildDir/intermediates/classes/debug"))
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }

    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    // Some dependencies (must obfuscate for client)

    // Robolectric
    testCompile('junit:junit:4.12') {
        exclude module: 'hamcrest-core'
    }
    testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0'
    testCompile 'org.robolectric:shadows-support-v4:3.0'
    testCompile 'org.robolectric:shadows-multidex:3.0'

    // Cobertura
    testCompile "org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.10"
}
```

I have tried many solutions I found scattered around the internet, but none of them seems to work.
It seems that the Android SDK is not properly set up for the Cobertura process. 
One thing I noticed is that the missing Android classes are all in the "android.content.x" package and the "org.json.x" package.
Any support is welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

While looking into a similar problem myself I came across these pages, hopefully they help:

- [gradle-cobertura-plugin/issues/124](https://github.com/stevesaliman/gradle-cobertura-plugin/issues/124)
- [gradle-cobertura-plugin/issues/57](https://github.com/stevesaliman/gradle-cobertura-plugin/issues/57)